# Improve computation time linear programing with cvxopt and mosek

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python

I'm looking for ways to improve the computation time in my optimization

My problem is in the form

$$
\min p^T \cdot q + |c| \\
\text{lower bound} \leq q \leq \text{upper bound} \\
\text{lower bound} \leq c \leq \text{upper bound} \\
Aq + Bc = d \\
Rq \leq \text{bound}
$$

Where $p, d$ are vectors and $A, B, R$  are sparse matrices and $q, c$ are variables.

The matrices $A,B.R$ are very large and very sparse and have a repeating pattern. So I was curious if there could be some improvement. The problem is a on hourly basis, which means that the pattern will repeat for every hour.

Basically in $q$ the first $17$ variables corresponds to the first hour, variables $18-35$ corresponds to the second hour, variables $36-53$ corresponds to the third hour and so on.

In $A$ the block corresponding to first hour looks like this

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1 \\
q_2 \\
q_3 \\
q_5 \\
\vdots \\
q_{17} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The rest of $A$ is just the same block shifted to the "right and down" so that it "hits" $q_{18} - q_{35}$, $q_{36} - q_{53}$ and so on

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1 \\
q_2 \\
q_3 \\
q_5 \\
\vdots \\
q_{35} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Matrix $B$ has the same behaviour with hour block "hitting" the first $8$ variables in $c$, second hour block hitting variables $9-17$, third hour hitting variables $18-26$ and so on. Where the block looks like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & \\
1  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 0  & 1  & 0  & 0  & \\
0  & 0  & 1  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 0  & 0  & \\
0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 1  & 0  & -1 & -1 & \\
0  & 1  & 0  & 1  & 0  & 1  & 0  & 1  & \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3 \\
c_5 \\
\vdots \\
c_{8} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The rest of $B$ is just the same block shifted to the "right and down" so that it "hits" $c_{9} - q_{17}$, $c_{18} - c_{26}$ and so on, just like in $A$

Now in matrix $R$ its taken into account what happend previous hour. So at hour $2$ we're looking at what happend at hour $1$. At hour $3$ we are looking at what happend at hour $2$ and $1$. Thus, at hour $i$ we are considering what happend at hour $1$ through $i-1$. This does not apply to all variables in $q$. It only applies to $4$ variables for each hour, i.e $q_{3 + 17k}, q_{6 + 17k}, q_{11 + 17k}, q_{15 + 17k}$.

This means that $Rq$ looks like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-q_3 \\
-q_6 \\
-q_{11} \\
-q_{15}  \\
q_3 \\
q_6 \\
q_{11} \\
q_{15} \\
-q_3 - q_{20}\\
-q_6 - q_{23} \\
-q_{11} - q_{28} \\
-q_{15} - q_{32} \\
q_3 + q_{20}\\
q_6 + q_{23} \\
q_{11} + q_{28} \\
q_{15} + q_{32} \\
\vdots \\
- \sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{3+17k} \\
- \sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{6+17k} \\
- \sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{11+17k} \\
- \sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{15+17k} \\
\sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{3+17k} \\
\sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{6+17k} \\
\sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{11+17k} \\
\sum_{k=0}^{N} q_{15+17k} 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

All matrices $A, B, R$ contain a lot of zeros and are large. My thinking is that there perhaps is a better way to formulate this, how the problem is formulated mathematically or how its implemented in code. All matrices are implemented as spare matrices with the function spmatrix in cvxopt.

```
problem = op(sum(prod_price) + 1e-6*sum(abs(c)), [q >= q_lower_bound, q <= q_upper_bound, -1*c <= -1*c_lower_bound, c <= c_upper_bound, A * q + B * c == d, R * q <= bound])
```

Current setup
A is a $26058 \times 73831$ matrix

B is a $26058 \times 34744$ matrix

R is a $34744\times 73831$ matrix

and it takes about 30 minutes to solve

**Edit**
I'm not looking for a high accuracy in the solution. Accuracy at $10^{-1}$ is enough. Currently trying to go through the different options that can be set to solver to see if computation time can be decreased with less accuracy.

Comment: For this type of question a programming forum or directly https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mosek (if using Mosek) would be more suitable. Sharing the full log output from the solver is a minimum good start to investigate. Set verbosity to True if necessary.